# TSQL - Build dynamic Exec for multi Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare  @table1 TABLE([Len] int, Values Nvarchar(1000) );

Declare  @table2 (sqlInsert NVARCHAR(MAX))
Declare @sql = "Insert Into @table2 Values ";

-- 1. Table store Values
INSERT INTO @table1 ([Len], Values)
VALUES (2, 'AB'), (3, 'BCD'), (4, 'CACA'), (2, 'DA'), (3, 'FAE'), (4, 'FAE'), (6, 'IGOALS'), (2, 'HA');

SELECT * FROM @table1
```

I want to build dynamic SQL multi inserts from values into `@table1`.

Example:

```
@sql = "Insert Into @table2 Values ('AB'), ('BCD'), ('CACA'), ('DA'), ('FAE'), ('FERE'), ('IGOALS'), ('HA')";
EXEC sp_executesql (@sql);
```

But, max of `Nvarchar` is 4000. That's why, I thought I should concat string values from `@table1`

Like this table (example range length > 5 then merge string values)

```
  Index | Sum(Len) | Name        | Description
--------+----------+-------------+--------------------------------   
    1   |   9      | AB,BCD,CACA | (Explain: First Sum(Len) > 5, Merge String)
    2   |   9      | DA,FAE,FAE  | (Explain:Second Sum(Len) > 5, Merge String)
    3   |   6      | IGOALS      | (Explain:Third, Sum(Len) > 5, Merge String)
    4   |   2      | HA          | (Explain:Last, still one last step)
```

Please, help me solution to have table like @table2 from Values in @table1.
Or You have another solution, suggest for me. 
Thank for your help.

Comment: It is very similar to the other your question. Be careful, your code in this one is wrong, does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution without using table2 and column Len could be this one. Hope this could help.

```
Declare  @table1 TABLE([Len] int, [Values] Nvarchar(1000) );

Declare  @table2 TABLE (sqlInsert NVARCHAR(MAX))
Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Insert Into @table2 Values ';

--1. Table store Values
INSERT INTO @table1 ([Len], [Values])
VALUES (2, 'AB'), (3, 'BCD'), (4, 'C''ACA'), (2, 'DA'), (3, 'FAE'), (4, 'FAE'), (6, 'IGOALS'), (2, 'HA');

SELECT * FROM @table1
-----
DECLARE @insert NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL
      , @Values NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE @maxLen INT = 4000 - LEN(@sql) - 2
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT '''' + REPLACE([Values], '''', '''''') + '''' from @table1;
print @maxLen
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Values
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@insert) + LEN(@Values) > @maxLen
       BEGIN
            SET @insert = @sql + '(' + @insert + ')'
            print  @insert  
            --INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES (@insert)
            --EXEC sp_executesql (@insert);     
            SET @insert = @Values;
       END
    ELSE
       BEGIN
            SET @insert = isnull(@insert + ',', '') + @Values
       END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Values
END

SET @insert = @sql + '(' + @insert + ')'
print  @insert  
--INSERT* INTO @table2 VALUES (@insert)
--EXEC sp_executesql (@insert);     

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur 


--SELECT * FROM @table2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's work for me. With your code, I inserted 734 Items about 4 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, my code was wrong, the quotes were missing. I've correct it. For higher performance, try also to perform inserts inside a single transaction. Furthermore, if the destination table has several indexes, sometimes it is better to disable them and rebuild them at the end of processing.

Comment: I had try with 8000 rows. Insert with  this code, performance down. Are performance for open BIG transaction will down? with 8000 rows need 3-4min. I split 800 (loop 10) , It's improve  process in 1 mins,